# Parsing a XML from URL with no .xml extension

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing

I'm learning `XML` parsing with Android Studio, reading and trying the code I get from tutorials. All material I had read teach you how to get info from `URL` with a `/some.xml` file (with the extension `.xml`) at the end.

I'm trying to parse a `xml` file hosted in a `URL` type http://something.com/file and I don't know what to put in the

```
String URL = "https://something.com/file";
```

part of the code. There is no `xml` extension in the `URL`.

What shall I do?

Greets.

Comment: What have you tried? Where is it failing? Post your code as a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether or not the URL has .xml at the end does not matter. As long as you know there is XML data at that URL, any code you are using should work.